# XCode 4 does not showing intellesence for my new Applications?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4, intellisense

In my Xcode if i created new project it does not giving intellegence and i have to type all the Manual. It makes pretty difficult me. Why it is happening. Is there any setting i have to modify. Please help me any one.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Sorry... intellisense is for MS dev tools. Your post reminded me of this - enjoy! : http://www.sdtimes.com/MAC_DEVELOPERS_EMBRACE_NET_WITH_VISUAL_OBJECTIVE_C/By_I_B__Phoolen/34234

Comment: Xcode intellisense tend to break when you're running the app on your phone rather than the simulator. What I tend to do is set the deploy target to simulator rather than iOS device, then it will pick up the intellisense. If it still doesn't work, the quick solution would be to do what Rocks suggested, delete your "Derived Data" in your Window > Organizer for your project. Then restart Xcode again. - Try to avoid the iOS device when typing code if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Fn + Esc will bring up a list of them, and you need to enable it in preferences

Answer (score 0):

```
intellegence window not Appear then follow the Step :)

1) Clean the project, in Xcode menu Product -> Clean
2) Close the project
3) Open Organizer and go to Projects tab, select the project
4)Remove all derived data (the buttons are on the main view : Derived data and Snapshots)
5)Remove the project from the list on the left (select it and press backspace)
6)Finally close Xcode, launch it again and reopen the project
```